# PowerShell tries to start outsider batch

Tags: powershell

I start Vim in PowerShell
Vim started successfully but before it drew its screen I saw the following:

`PS C:\Users\i320177> vim
    'RunDesigner.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\i320177>`

This `RunDesign.bat` does exist on my machine and I used Vim to edit it in past. But it is not used in any environment variables or similar stuff. Why PowerShell tries to start it before Vim? Where could it get it from?

Thanks.

**Update 1**
When I start Vim in that directory, then start both - Designer and Vim.

Comment: What do you have in your prompt function? `Get-Content Function:\prompt`

Comment: `PS C:\User\i32177> Get-Content Function:\prompt  
    $promptString = "PS " + $(Get-Location) + ">"  
    Write-Host $promptString -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green  
    return " "  
}
`

Comment: It is not PowerShell error message. It is CMD error message. What is `vim` (`.bat`,`.exe`)? Is same happens when you ran any other `.bat` or `.exe`?

Comment: Vim is .exe. If I ran rundesigner.bat from directory it resides it starts twice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454365/powershell-starts-batch-twice). If I ran Vim from that directory, they started both successfully.
At the moment no more .exe or .bat files behave similarly.