# PowerShell starts batch twice

Tags: powershell

I have the following function definition in my profile:

```
function design {
    Set-Location $env:CC72\Designer
    .\RunDesigner.bat
}
```

But when I execute the function `design`, PowerShell executes batch RunDesigner.bat twice and two instances of it are started:

```
PS C:\Users\s3201> design
Starting Designer...
Starting Designer...
PS C:\customer\Designer>
```

Why?

**Update 1**
The content of the batch is the following:
`set LOC_WIN32=c:\Customer\xxxxxx
set LOC_UNIX=c:/Customer/xxxxxxx
echo Starting Designer...
start %LOC_WIN32%\bin\xxxxxxx.exe %LOC_UNIX%/Designer/lib/xxxxxxxx.tcl -guiFile %1`

**Update 2**
If I start Vim from the directory where mentioned batch resides then they start both - Vim and batch file.
Therefore the reason for the message in begin of the question is clear - PowerShell tries to start that batch first, does not find it, writes the message and the starts Vim. But why it tries to start the that batch first?
Obviously, the root cause is in some PowerShell definitions. Which ones? (Aliases I checked).

Comment: what's in the .bat ?

Comment: Bat contains starting stuff. It was used many times from cmd.exe before I tried PowerShell. So bat's content is not the reason.

Comment: that's hard to guess based on the infos you gave us !

Comment: But you suggest it could happen because of bat's content (designed for cmd.exe earlier) which is incorrectly interpreted by the PowerShell. Correct?

Comment: correct, you have undertand me

Comment: Actually, there are four lines of code. See update.

Comment: checked if you have an alias ? `get-alias design ` . What if you move your design function to a file, start powershell with -noprofile and dot source the file ?

Comment: `get-alias design`  gives `no such alias`. Your trick gives no any change in behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83439/discussion-between-kayasax-and-olegg).